# Watson Assistant retaining the value that is a recognised entity

Tags: entity, watson-assistant

I am capturing a user response in my assistant, after which I want following questions to repsond based in the response that has been previously captured into an entity i have created

For example I will respond to a question with

Banana this is captured as an entity

I then want the watson assistant to then respond to subsequent question based on the entity captured. For example I want to ask

What colour ? and for the assistant to know that Im asking the question in relation to the banana, as I know that some people interacting with the assistant won't ask the question "what colour is a banana ?"

Comment: Do you mean context variables?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is one of the reasons (as @data_henrik mentioned) we have context variables. These once set will remain through out the conversation. You can set a context variable using either the context editor ( see three dot menu of a dialog node ) or in the json response packet i.e. 
"context": { 
   "my_saved_entity" : @entity_defined 
}
In your case @entity_defined = banana so "my_saved_entity" becomes banana.

You can then use this context variable in your response; 
The colour of a $my_saved_entity is Yellow

And you can text for a setting of $my_saved_entity in the dialog condition i.e. 
(if) $my_saved_entity = "banana" or the short hand version $my_saved_entity:banana 
I would suggest you read the following documentation, and have a play

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-runtime#dialog-runtime-context-variables